# Why did Allah create people when he already knew what was going to happen?

Tags: allah, creation, infallability, destiny

As Muslims we believe in destiny and that our fate has already been determined and our destiny has been written by God as he is all knowing.

So in essence, God knew what was going to happen with his creation before he created, he knew the good and the evil that was going to occur.

**With that being said, why did God decide to create us?** We cannot say it's a test because he already knew what will happen.

> “No calamity befalls on the earth or in yourselves but it is inscribed in the Book of Decrees (Al‑Lawh Al‑Mahfooz) before We bring it into existence. Verily, that is easy for Allaah - [al-Hadeed 57:22]

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification, not for argument and debate or extended discussion of tangential points.

Comment: almost the same question read this maybe can help -->https://islam.stackexchange.com/a/51702/30088

Comment: @benabdo That does not answer the question one bit and is in fact written very poorly. I can barely make out what the person is trying to say as they cannot formulate proper sentences.

Answer (score -1):

The answer to this is simple: If He did, it would be punishing people before the crime, and go against the concept of justice. He being All-Just thus did not do that. Otherwise people would argue that they would not have done evil actions if given the chance. Putting people through the physical test removes that argument.

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification, not for argument and debate or extended discussion of tangential points.

Comment: @goldPseudo I think it would be fair to at-least leave the first few comments that were made as they addressed this answer. I understand the others were getting a little off-topic.